# Customer and product page gives error

Tags: magento

Customer and product page in magento admin gives an error when save and back :

> The record cannot be found. There is error in processing your request.

[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: Please check screenshot to click "enter image description here link".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to track back in your code where the error is thrown. *'There is error in processing your request.'* isn't an error message that is thrown by Magento itself (you can check the codebase for this string). Given the poor translation of the error message, could it be that a 3rd party plugin is throwing this error?

Comment: thanks youe suggestion, but i m getting this error after delete an address attribute from database eav_attribute table.

Comment: If you directly deleted the attribute from the database you might have to check other tables if there are any broken references to the attribute. You should try to avoid deleting stuff hard from the database as much as possible, but do it using the proper models in Magento. Still, I think that your problem is caused by a 3rd party extension. Have you looked for the string _'There is error in processing'_ in your codebase?